# Checbox click event is triggered while binding table rows

Tags: knockout.js

I have a checkbox column in a table. I want to trigger event only if user clicks on checkbox. But, in my case the even is getting triggered even while binding the table rows.

Event on view model

```
 self.UpdateData = function (item, value) {               
                $.ajax({                       
                })
            });
```

This is how I am binding it.

```
 data-bind="checked: flag, click: $root.UpdateData($parent.RowNumber(), flag())"
```

Can anyone let me know why the `UpdateData()` event is getting triggered while rendering the table rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Knockout doesn't allow you to provide an expression to the `click` binding. If you're interested in binding this way, check out my [Knockout.Punches](http://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/) plugin. If not, you must wrap your expression in an anonymous function:

```
click: function() { $root.UpdateData($parent.RowNumber(), flag()); }
```

Second, you'll find another problem after you do this. Your `click` handler will prevent the checkbox from being changed because, by default, Knockout prevents the default behavior for event when they're bound. To enable the default behavior, you need to add `return true` to the function:

```
click: function() { $root.UpdateData($parent.RowNumber(), flag()); return true; }
```

Third, I'd suggest you try to avoid adding a `click` binding with a checkbox. You already have the `checked` binding, which updates an observable with the checkbox's status. You also have the option to bind `checked` to an array, in which case it adds or removes the value of the checkbox from the array:

```
data-bind="attr: {value: $parent.RowNumber()}, checked: $root.selectedRows"
```